# Excel Numbering and Subnumbering

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to achieve this info in column B with a function so I can fill it down a very long database, is it applicable?

[image: Example Photo]

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Excel 365 you can use `FILTER` and `UNIQUE`.

I inserted a table for the data --> with that the formulas are more self explaining.

Furthermore I added helper columns to create the single IDs per column. I prefer this method - as I think it is easier to understand than one complex formula.

[image]

The formulas are:

IDFamily: `=MATCH([@Family],UNIQUE([Family]),0)`

IDItem: `=MATCH([@Item],UNIQUE(FILTER([Item],[Family]=[@Family])),0)`

IDColor: `=MATCH([@Color],UNIQUE(FILTER([Color],([Family]=[@Family])*([Item]=[@Item]))),0)`

All these formulas retrieve a subset of data based on the left  values (unique and filtered), e.g. "Orange, Banana, Apple" for Family "Fruits"

Then the index of the value (e.g. for apple) is returned (= 3rd item of subset) as the ID for Item Apple.

S/N: `=TEXTJOIN(".",TRUE,Table1[@[IDFamily]:[IDColor]])`

Answer (score 2):

For those without Office 365:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIFS($B$2:$B2,$B$2:$B2))&"."&
SUMPRODUCT(($B$2:$B2=B2)/COUNTIFS($B$2:$B2,$B$2:$B2,$C$2:C2,$C$2:C2))&"."&
SUMPRODUCT((($B$2:$B2=B2)*($C$2:C2=C2))/COUNTIFS($B$2:$B2,$B$2:$B2,$C$2:C2,$C$2:C2,$D$2:D2,$D$2:D2))
```

One note, it requires that the data be sorted by Fruit,Item.

[image]

Comment: if you may give us a few insight of the formula of how it works, if that would be fine? @Scott Craner